# open modal popup on external link

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to open a modal popup when user click on an external link, and if click yes on the button, can proceed to the link...

if not, he remain into the site., but i do not know how to tell that if click on ok, he can proceed to the clicked link..

here my code so far:

```
  jQuery('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
  }).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.hostname !== location.hostname)
    return Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {

      }
    })
    {
      // if user clicks 'no' then dont proceed to link.
      e.preventDefault();
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the latest version of jquery and swal. But should be pretty much the same.

```js
$(function() {
  var allLinks = $("a").filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
  }).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You are about to open an external url.",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        // document.location.href = this.href; // if you want it to open in same window
        window.open(this.href); // will open it in new window
      }
    });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://google.com">Go to Google</a> - 
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Go to Stackoverflow</a> - 
<a href="test.html">Internal Link (Broken)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

before u coming with this answer (thank u so much)

i'm actually found a way using:

```
window.location = this.href;
```

is this correct?

Comment: That's correct if you want to open it in the same window. If you want to open it in new window use `window.open` instead.

Comment: thank u very much, the real problem is, can i retrieve the url of clicked link? so i can use it into modal

Comment: `this.href` will give you the url of clicked link.